# Visual Studio 2022 error related to MKL, cant load Intel.Build.ICLTasks.v160.dll

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, intel-mkl, visual-studio-2022

My C# project works with Intel Math Kernal Library when using Visual studio 2019.
I just installed VS 2022 and tried to build the project using old toolset (v142).

It fails to build with this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4062 The "ICMessage" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Msbuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Intel.Build.ICLTasks.v160.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Msbuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Intel.Build.ICLTasks.v160.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.    StreamsProcessor    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Msbuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v142\ImportAfter\Intel.Libs.MKL.v142.targets  37
```

This is the file that defines to build with MKL.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <UsingTask TaskName="ICMessage" AssemblyFile="$(VCTargetsPath)Intel.Build.ICLTasks.v160.dll" Condition="'$(PlatformToolset)' == 'v142'"/>

<!--"Could not expand {0} variable. Corresponsing version of Intel(R) MKL is not installed or the registry information may be incorrect."-->
  <Target Name="CheckIntelEnvironmentForVCLibsMKL" BeforeTargets="ClCompile" Condition="'$(UseIntelMKL)' != '' AND '$(UseIntelMKL)' != 'No' AND '$(UseEnv)' != 'true' AND '$(PlatformToolset)' == 'v142'">
    <ICMessage Code="WRN001" Type="Warning" Arguments="MKLProductDir;MKL"  Condition="'$(MKLProductDir)'==''" />
    <ICMessage Code="WRN001" Type="Warning" Arguments="MKLMajorVersion;MKL" Condition="'$(MKLMajorVersion)'==''" />
    <ICMessage Code="WRN001" Type="Warning" Arguments="MKLMinorVersion;MKL" Condition="'$(MKLMinorVersion)'==''" />
    <ICMessage Code="WRN001" Type="Warning" Arguments="MKLIncludeDir;MKL"  Condition="'$(MKLIncludeDir)'==''" />
    <ICMessage Code="WRN001" Type="Warning" Arguments="MKLLibDir;MKL" Condition="'$(MKLLibDir)'==''" />
    <ICMessage Code="WRN001" Type="Warning" Arguments="OmpLibDir;MKL" Condition="'$(OmpLibDir)'==''" />
  </Target>
```

I checked the file is there `Intel.Build.ICLTasks.v160.dll` and seems like both versions search it on the same place but for some reason VS 2022 fails to find it.
Can you hint how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2022 is a 64 bit app.  Might be trying to load a 32 bit dll.  I have been fighting something similar in some build tasks in a dll.  If I get a solution, I will edit this answer.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this error I installed Intel C/C++ compilers
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=intel-corporation.dpcpponline